# Sum integers using a loop c#

Tags: c#, loops, integer, sum

I am  new to programming and I think I have confused myself I'm trying to make a loop that asks users for integers when the user inputs a integer greater than 100 then the console displays the amount of integers the user has input and the sum of these integers. I know it's basic but I can't figure where I went wrong.

```
namespace Wip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strNum1, strNum2;
            int num1, num2;
            int i = 0;
            int sum =0 ;              

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a integer between 1 and 100"); // asks for user input
            strNum1 = Console.ReadLine();
            num1 = int.Parse(strNum1);

            do //repeat asking for user input
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer between 1 and 100"); // asks for user input
                strNum2 = Console.ReadLine();
                num2 = int.Parse(strNum2); //input is stored as num2
                sum = num2; //store num2 in sum
                i++; 
                if (num2 >= 100) // if num2 int is greater than 100
                {
                    sum = (num1 +num2  +sum); // do calculation
                    Console.WriteLine("No of integers entered is {0} {1}", i, sum); //output calculation 
                }
            }
            while (i < 100);
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated thanks everyone!

Comment: When the entered value is > 100 do you want to include it in the sum and should it also exit?  If it should not exit should it continue with the existing sum, or start over?  Right now you keep going until the user enters 100 numbers.  But in general your problem is that you are not summing the number as you go and thus you lose some along the way.

Comment: You probably meant `sum += num2;`, not `sum = num2;`, because the latter just resets your sum on each iteration to the current number 2.

Comment: Have you tried debugging through your code to see where the value is being set incorrectly, or using breakpoints to stop code execution at the relevant lines? The answers below will tell you what you did wrong, but you'd be better off if you debugged your own code and found your error.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with += could somebody please explain? Apologies about the crappy questions but I'm new to programming. You guys are great for not flaming me! Thanks!

Comment: @CC1331 It's the [addition assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) basically `x += y;` is just short of `x = x + y;`.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track... a couple of things:

`Do... While` is used when you always want to run through the block at least once, so your first 'get' from the user can be inside the block. You can code whatever you want to happen *after* the condition fails right after the block, instead of checking the same condition inside it.

Make sure if you're simply using `Parse` that you wrap it in a `try...catch`, because your user could type in anything (not just numbers). Personally I usually use `TryParse` instead.

Finally, make sure you're comparing to the correct variable. Checking that `i < 100` will keep looping until 100 numbers have been entered; you want to compare the user's input instead.

```
namespace Wip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string prompt = "Please enter {0} integer between 1 and 100";
            string strNum;
            int num = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int sum =0 ;              

            do //ask once and repeat while 'while' condition is true
            {
                string pluralPrompt = i > 0 ? "another" : "an";
                prompt = string.Format(prompt,pluralPrompt);
                Console.WriteLine(prompt); // asks for user input
                strNum = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!Int32.TryParse(strNum, out num)) //input is stored as num
                {
                    // warn the user, throw an exception, etc.
                }

                sum += num; //add num to sum
                i++; 

            }
            while (num < 100);

            Console.WriteLine("No of integers entered is {0} {1}", i, sum); //output calculation 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Wip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strNum;
            int num;
            int i = 0;
            int sum = 0;

            do //repeat asking for user input
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer between 1 and 100"); // asks for user input
                strNum = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(strNum, out num)) //input is stored as num2
                {
                    if (num < 101) 
                    {
                        i++;


     sum += num;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No of integers entered is {0} {1}", i, sum); //output calculation 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (i < 100);

    }
}
```